# PHP. Как правильно построить условия проверки данных

Tags: php

Мне нужно понять. В какой из переменных находится неправильная данная(которая не равняется другим)

```
$qty = 3;
$countShortDescription = 2;
$countImages = 2;

if (
    !empty($countShortDescription)
    AND !empty($qty)
    AND !empty($countImages)
) {
    //If everything is equal
    if (
        $countShortDescription == $qty
        AND $qty == $countImages
        AND $countShortDescription == $countImages
    ) {
        var_dump('все одинаково');
        exit;
    }
} else {
    continue;
}
```

Comment: вам не кажется, что это все одинаковые условия?

Comment: Да. Но мне нужно понять. В какой из переменных находится неправильная данная(которая не равняется другим)

Comment: вот так и написали бы задачу, есть три переменных, надо выяснить, какая из трех отличается от двух оставшихся. и могут ли все три быть различными

Answer (score 1):

думаете, здесь можно написать какое-то шибко элегантное решение, кроме влоб?

```
if($a == $b && $b == $c){
    // все равны
} 
elseif( $a == $b){
    // ошибка в $c
}
elseif( $a == $c){
    //ошибка в $b
}
else {
    //ошибка в $a
}
```

это если не рассматривать вариант, что все три вообще различны, в том случае не скажешь, какая из них "неправильная".